# How to create and implement a small database on Mathematica?

Tags: dataset, databases

I have a function

```
f[x_,y_,z_]:= a^x b^y c^z
```

and I want to evaluate it for various values of x,y,z always coming in triples. This means I have a database with columns x,y,z and rows vectors say A,B,C. (Sorry I could not write a Latex table here for some reason!)

How does one create such a table on Mathematica and then asks the function to directly compute 1) f[vector A] instead f[x,y,z] and 2) say the sum or product of vectors A,B, and C?

Comment: E.g. `f @@ {X, Y, Z}` - see [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)

Comment: I believe you would be best served either with `Dataset`, which has a convenient (and I think optimized) `Query` syntax, or with `Association`, from which you can `Lookup`. That said, there are probably a dozen different ways to get this done.

Comment: You can use `\begin{bmatrix} ... \end{bmatrix}` if you want to draw a table with mathjax.

Comment: The title mentions a database, and the answer below describes how to make a `Dataset`, but the question seems to be only about how to apply a function to a list of vectors.  For this all you need is `f @@@ {A,B,C}`.  Don't make a `Dataset` if you don't plan to use the querying functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend looking into Dataset.

Here is a test dataset:

```
data = Dataset@
  Table[<|"x" -> RandomReal[], "y" -> RandomReal[], 
    "z" -> RandomReal[]|>, {i, 9}]
```

Then you can apply your function like this:

```
f[data[1, "x"], data[1, "y"], data[1, "z"]]
```

or shorter:

```
f @@ data[1]
```

Which applies your function to the first row (or row vector A in your question).

With a dataset you can use Total like this to get a sum per row:

```
data[1, Total]
```